# MSCRM Sitemap link to .htm page. How do I pass parameters?

Tags: c#, html, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-4

I have a Site Map link that opens up a Web Resource .htm page. Everything works great except I want to pass some values to that page. I assumed I could pass them as a querystring since there is the Xrm.Page.context.getQueryStringParameters() method but my querystring seems to get stripped out.

```
<SubArea Icon="$webresource:my_webresourceicon.gif"Id="nav_my_webresourceid" Url="$webresource:my_webresourcepage.htm?xyz=123" Client="All" AvailableOffline="false" Title="My Web Resource Page" Description="My Web resource Description" Sku="All" PassParams="true"/>
```

I want to be able to access the parameter xyz from my_webresourcepage.htm as the page loads. What is the best way to go about passing this value?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't pass xyz unless you modify the registry.  Instead, you want to use the parameter "data".

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309536.aspx

Comment: So instead of "Url="$webresource:my_webresourcepage.htm?xyz=123"" 
I should have "Url="$webresource:my_webresourcepage.htm?Data=EncodedParameters""

Comment: That's right.  Although, I always use a lower case "d".  It shouldn't be case-sensitive, but I haven't tested it.

Comment: Hi Paul, sorry for coming to this old question. but is it possible to specify the data parameter in the sitemap xml, did that really worked for you? 
I can set the passparams to 1 and get the orglcid, orgname etc..  but if I add ?data=helloworld i have an empty window.location.search in the webresource.. could somebody confirm that?